# Not Sure How to Resolve this ValueError: Data Cardinality is Ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN on data taken from images of cats and dogs. Here is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((32, 32, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

opt = keras.optimizers.legacy.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6)


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=opt,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(cd_train_inputs.shape, cd_train_labels.shape, 
                validation_data=(cd_test_inputs.shape, cd_test_labels.shape), \
                epochs=70)
print(model.summary())
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 4
  y sizes: 1
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

When calling `model.fit()` you want to pass the underlying X and y data, not the shape of the tensors:

```py
history = model.fit(
    cd_train_inputs,
    cd_train_labels, 
    validation_data=(cd_test_inputs, cd_test_labels),
    epochs=70
)
```